# need help identifying where and how to modify an existing project to add a plugin

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've written tons of working python, but mostly single file scripts and sysadmin/automation stuff.  I'm not a software developer, so I don't typically work with multi-file python projects.

I want to modify the letsencrypt.org client to create a plugin, and their plugin architecture is just a bit over my head.  I have just 4 questions about this file here:

https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt/blob/master/letsencrypt/plugins/webroot.py

1. how would I modify it so that the path (the location that it writes out to) is always just ./ (e.g. right next to my current working path.  and 1a) what bits are no longer needed and can then be removed once that is hardcoded ?
2. where in the project is webroot.py (or webroot.authenticator class) being called, and how can I modify that to remove the path parameter, since I don't need it anymore?
3. I think know how to add additional class methods to webroot.authenticator, but for the life of me I don't see where in the project its *existing* methods are being called, so that I can examine them, see how/where they are being called, and duplicate that for the methods I added.  Can you point me to an example? for example, where is webroot.authenticator.perform() being called from?
4. Once I am happy with the way it works, I want to make it available (to me only at first) as a plugin.  I realize that I'd simply put my finished .py in letsencrypt/letsencrypt/plugins/myPlugin.py.  However, what parent .py(s) would I need to modify in order to call my plugin properly as an argument (like --webroot is)?